# Toast from FileObserver

Tags: android, toast

I have a problem. I'm using a `FileObserver`, which moves new files from the watched directories to another, former specified directory. In my thoughts there should be shown a toast message that says 'File xy has been moved', as long as the observer watches the directory, also if the applications is only in the background. But I didn't get it working.
It always tells me, that there is a `RuntimeException`, and that it cannot been done without calling `Looper.prepare()`.

> 05-11 13:21:28.484:
>   WARN/System.err(3397):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't
>   create handler inside thread that has
>   not called Looper.prepare()

I tried the way with using an handler too, but I also didn't get it to work.

Has someone else an idea?
Thanks in advance.

Best regards, Tobi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, your FileObserver runs(or is) another thread. You can not modify the UI from non-UI thread. Pass a Handler to your FileObserver and send messages from it. Read about [Handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Comment: Thanks, this helped! I just understood the handler concept wrong. Now it is working. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It would be great if the question or answer could be update to provide a sample code.  I am working with same issue but do not see how to use Handler correctly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Before your Toast statement add the following :

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

This will make it run on UI thread.
Hope this helps.

Comment: runOnUiThread is the method which belong to Activity,so thecode snippset must write in Activity.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for the context of the Toast message?  That will have to have a way to display something on the screen.

Comment: I'm using the the application context. I give it from the main activity to the observer.

Comment: See both posts regarding handlers.

Answer (score -1):

Put the following code in your class:

```
// Need handler for callbacks to UI Threads
    // For background operations
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    // Create Runnable for posting results
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Show the toast here.
        }
    };
```

and in your fileobserver's thread call place following fragment of code:

```
mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
```

and don't use the `getApplicationContext()` instead try `YourClassPhysicalName.java` for the context of the Toast.