# Toast Notification From FileObserver Class

Tags: java, android

I have an issue similar to [Toast from FileObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963438/toast-from-fileobserver).  However, I do not understand how to properly implement the Handler.

Currently, I have a `FileObserver`-class and I am passing it context and a handler (context comes from `getApplicationContext()` from the service I call the `FileObserver`-class from). The handler I pass in (handle) is defined and created in the service. In the `onEvent()` of the `FileObserver`-class, I have:

```
handle.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
});
```

But, I end up with a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

How do I properly make the toast notification show up when I send it from the `onEvent()` of the `FileObserver`-class?

Comment: Please post the full LogCat output. Also, if this is for debugging only, you might want to use the [`Log`-class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html).

Comment: I got it! Context wasn't doing it, but getBaseContext was.